# How to rename services in soapUI

Tags: refactoring, rename, soapui

I'm having an hard time trying to rename/refactor my service in soapUI. I right clicked on my service on the Navigator pane but there's no "Rename" option in the context menu.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Go to Service Properties pane on the bottom left rename it there.